# Showing function is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I'm trying to show that a function is well defined, I've already read some topics on this but I really can't tell if I'm doing this right. Basically I'm trying to show that $\phi: G \subset \mathbb{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(A) = \log(a_{11})$ is well defined, where $G$ is the set of matrices of the form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
0 & \frac{1}{a_{11}}
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad a_{11} > 0.
$$

I thought that as $a_{11} > 0$ and if $A = B$, $A, B \in G$, then $\log(a_{11}) = \log(b_{11})$, then it is well defined. Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $G$ is a set of $2\times2$ matrices such that $A_{1,1}>0$ for every $A\in G$ then automatically the function $G\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $A\mapsto\log A_{1,1}$ is well defined on $G$. This because the LHS $A$ completely determines the RHS $\log A_{1,1}$.

Comment: Why do you think you need this part: "if $A=B$, $A,B\in G$, then $log(a_{11})=log(b_{11})$"? (which, incidentally, holds irrespective of $A$ and $B$ laying in $G$, by definition of equality between matices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this function is well defined because the following remark: The domain of the log function is the set of positive real numbers. Then, since $a_{11}>0$ for all matrix $M \in G$ this definição is good.